# Make content only visible if CheckBox is checked

Tags: hyperref, forms

I have a ChoiceMenu with three options:

- No
- Option 1
- Option 2

If Option 1 or Option 2 are clicked I want that a furhter text and a TextField is displayed. I don't want that it is possible to write a text in the field belonging to Option 2 if the button is clicked on Option 1. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{makecell,
  tabularx}           
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref} 


\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[{\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=example,radiosymbol=\ding{108}]{}{=no}}] 
  No.
  \item[{\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=example,radiosymbol=\ding{108}]{}{=one}}]
  Option 1 \TextField[name=textone]{, since }

  \item[{\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=example,radiosymbol=\ding{108}]{}{=two}}]
  Option 2 \TextField[name=texttwo]{, since }
\end{itemize}

\end{Form}
```

I want, i.e., that the TextField `textone` with its text is only visible if for 
`one` is chosen for `example`.
Is there a way to to this?